# Is std::filesystem::directory_entry canonical?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, boost-filesystem

I'm on Windows (case-insensitive but case-preserving file system) and I have to deal with various input paths (user provided and machine generated), which may or may not be canonical (normalized, absolute, in the right case...). I'm going to use fs::path as keys in maps and sets. For performance reasons, there I want to be able to rely on pure string comparison / hashes. So I have to canonicalize all the input paths.

The problem is that I'm recursively iterating over one of the input paths. When I start this iteration with a non-canonical root path, the resulting directory_entries are non-canonical too. But when I start the iteration with a canonical root path, the resulting directory_entries seem to be canonical too. So, the root part seems to depend on the initial root path. Now I was wondering if there is any guarantee that the iterated part is canonical or not? If not, I have to canonicalize every directory_entry, but I would like to avoid that extra access to the file system.

I found nothing on cppreference.com and a quick perusal of a standardeze paper about the filesystem library yielded nothing either.

```
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

void scan_folder(fs::path const & root_path) {
    for (auto & entry : fs::recursive_directory_iterator{root_path}) {
        // entry.path() == root_part / iterative_part
        // root_part == root_path, depends on root_path being canonical
        // but what about iterative_part?
        _ASSERTE(entry.path() == fs::canonical(entry.path()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't what you call "iterative_part" just the name of the directory?

Comment: @bolov It could be anything that comes after the root part, maybe a single directory or file name or a chain of directories plus a file name. Depends on the depth and content of that particular directory tree.

Comment: `directory_iterator` doesn't descend recursively into the tree. It just iterates over the directories in path, just 1 level

Comment: @bolov I know, it's taken from my actual code where I scan each level separately and then explicitly dive deeper into sub folders by calling my function recursively after I'm done with the current level. Edited my code example, hope it's clearer now.